# Datatype for notepad file in MySql database

Tags: mysql

I want to create a page which will upload text file(notepad) to database. I want to know which Datatype we should use?

Comment: `text` if you want to store the contents, `blob` if you want to store the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a "notepad file" is just a plain text file, [the text datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) seems like the obvious choice.

Comment: File as `'text'` or content as `'text'`? See [*comment by EWit*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237844/datatype-for-notepad-file-in-mysql-database#comment37434345_24237844)

Comment: @Ravinder for a notepad file those should be identical since there is no extra padding on the file itself. I suggested `blob` more because requirements or syntax could change. storing in `text` means parsing from/to files. And using `blob` negates the need for that. just dump all the bytes and done. Both have their ups and downs.

Comment: @Mureinik  I set datatype in table as TEXT.now my doubt is what should i choose in java class to set it.should i use setString() ?

Comment: @afsalparangooz: Java String can hold `'2^31-1'` chars. Total size `'4 GB'`. You can use `'setString'` to set the text, when it is within the said size limit.

Comment: @Ravinder But the input is a FILE. we can't add File type using setString.right??

Comment: @afsalparangooz Question: Do you want to store the "text" or the "file"? The `text` datatype can be used to store the file contents (i.e. read file -> toString -> store read data in DB). The `blob` type can store the entire file (i.e. read file -> store binary data). (For a simple text file the actual data is identical no matter what datatype is chosen.) If you wish to support ODF, RDF, DOC, DOCX etc. then there is an actual difference to concern yourself about.

Comment: And hence is my first comment.

Comment: I want to store File as 'text'.